# How to raise an object using css

Tags: css

I would like to know how to move the lie detector up

```
.notebookLink {    
  font-size: 85%;    
  text-align: right;    
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;      
}

.detectorLink {
  font-size: 85%;    
  text-align: left;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYGe6.png

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Change the top and left to move

Comment: I think it's not a good solution using position:Absolute. we don't know how is OP's Html

Comment: I assumed that they are on different containers since they are stacked (or wrapped) as seen in the picture. Unless OP will resize them so they can fit in the same line, position: absolute would be a sure-fire solution

Comment: @keijeizei you're making a huge assumption based on seeing no code.